# Can I continue my previously developed idea in my new work place?

Tags: research-process, job, independent-researcher, government-institutes

I had developed a research idea with my colleagues in my previous work place. However, recently I have left the job and joined in a new work place. I also know that none of the colleagues in my previous institute are willing to continue this research idea. So I am wondering whether can I continue the same research idea in my new work place? One thing I can do is I should ask the permission from my previous team or collaborate with them.

I am an atmospheric researcher, previously worked in a research institute and presently working in another research institute.

Looking forward for some suggestions in this regard.

Comment: The first permission you need is from who pays you if they are okay with you using your time and maybe even their infrastructure to continue that project.

Comment: Why possibly not?

Comment: If your prior employer or institution has any ownership of your idea, some care may be required.  If the idea is yours alone, I see no problem of moving on with your research, assuming your new employer supports it.